# running a python script once on deploy on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis

I have flask app that uses `geodis` which has dependency on `redis` that acts as cache for city mapped to latitude and longitude from `geodis`.

I have this code that needs to be run just once on deployment of the flask web app on heroku,

```
from geodis.provider.geonames import GeonamesImporter
import geodis
fileName = os.path.split(geodis.__file__)[0] + "/data/cities1000.json"
importer = GeonamesImporter(fileName, os.getenv("REDIS_HOST"), os.getenv("REDIS_PORT"), 0)
importer.runimport()
```

How can I have it setup to run once on deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think one way is to use application initialization function.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileName = os.path.split(geodis.__file__)[0] + "/data/cities1000.json"
    importer = GeonamesImporter(fileName,
                                os.getenv("REDIS_HOST"),
                                os.getenv("REDIS_PORT"), 0)
    importer.runimport()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=app.config['PORT'])
```

this would run it before creating the app.

Comment: Thanks, cities1000.json file when uploaded to redis db becomes 79Mb and hobby-Dev plan doesn't support more than 25 mb, so sadly I had to discard the plan of using geodis.

Comment: did the code do the job and only problem was the size?

Comment: well I attempted, but it gave maxmeory error, and cannot continue due to size limit. thanks of your help